# What is the name of this chaotic sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

A long time ago I came across a chaotic sequence of the form

```
x[n+1] = f(x[n], y[n])
y[n+1] = g(x[n], y[n])
```

If I remember correctly, `f` and `g` are simple polynomials of maximum order 3, but I am not sure if they also included other functions. The functions also had a number of parameters that could be varied.

Plotting the points `(x[n],y[n])` produces intersting patterns that grow around a center point, often creating flower-like shapes. The shapes have no exact symmetry but typically an odd number of similar regions that are rotated around the center point, but in a distorted way.

I am not sure where I originally found a description of that system but it could have been a very old Scientific American article probably from the late 1980s.

Not much information, I know, but hopefully sufficient for someone who knows that system.

Comment: Just to make sure: have you checked examples from the [list of chaotic maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chaotic_maps)? For example, [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(discrete_dynamical_systems)) is pretty similar to your description.

Comment: @evgeny: Yes I have checked this list and no it is not the exponential map. The variables x and y are not components of a complex number.